# how to call a struts2 action on click of a row from jQuery grid

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery, jqgrid

i have a jsp page where i am displaying my books detail in Struts2 jquery grid.
Now i want to call an action and pass rowid as a  parameter to the the action class on the click of a row from my Jquery grid. And i also i want to specify the target of my div to refresh after calling my action.

These stuffs i know nicely through `<sj:submit target="targetDivToRefresh" formId="form2" button="true"/>`   but i don't know how to do these task "when users click a row from my struts2 jquery grid".

Please help me to solve this issue.

### my jsp page

```
    <sjg:grid
        id="bookgrid" 
        editurl="%{bookediturl}"
        navigator="true" 
        editinline="true" 
        navigatorSearch="false"
        autowidth="false"   
        width= "1550" 
        viewrecords="true"  
        navigatorRefresh="true"
        navigatorDelete="true">
    <sjg:gridColumn name="id" index="locationId" title="ID" formatter="integer" sortable="false" key="true" 
                       search="false"  editable="true"  hidden="true"   /> 
     <sjg:gridColumn name="authLastname" index="authLastname" title="AuthorLastname" sortable="true" search="true" editrules="{required: true}"
                        editable="true" edittype="text" />  
 </sjg:grid>
```

Comment: you'd like to build another button to edit a row or you can easily use the integrated edit button in the grid?

Comment: @Jaiwo99 Sorry, But My question is not for edit purpose. I already completed row edit tasks from inline or through external button. Please read my question once again. I want to call an action when a users click on a row and also i want to specify the div target when the action completed its execution. i know how to do this through a struts2 form but i do't know with grid. With form  we use to call a form and specify targets like this -> `<sj:submit target="targetDivToRefresh" formId="form2" button="true"/>` . Please help me. -Thankyou

Comment: OK, I understand you now, you should register the `rowselect` event. I will post the example code for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$(function(){
    $.subscribe('rowselect', function(event,data) {
        alert(event.originalEvent.authLastname);
        $("#targetDivToRefresh").load('your-struts2-action');
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
$("#targetDivToRefresh").load('your-struts2-action');
```

Reference Link: [Struts2 jquery plugin showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action)

Please make sure this event will be triggered, if you click on a row, i added test code `alert()` to make sure, it has been called during the event. there is still a thing, that i have to tell, you have to register your `selectrow` event in your `<sj:grid>` tag using `onSelectRowTopics="rowselect"`

**UPDATE**

```
$("#targetDivToRefresh").load("<s:url value="your-struts2-action"/>"+"?id="+event.originalEvent.id);
```

Comment: please elaborate on your suggested solution. explain why use this approach, or provide a solid reference for your findings.

Comment: @Jaiwo99 I tried your new updated answer. But still it is not calling my action only alert is coming fine.

Comment: @Jaiwo99  I tried your new update. with that in my target div the value "your-struts2-action" is displaying. But it is not calling my action class. i mapped a action name "test" in my struts.xml and also wrote a java class. But still it is not calling my action. i tried like this `$("#targetDivToRefresh").html('<s:url value="test"/>');` even i tried this also -> `$("#myAdvanceDivBoxx").html('<s:url action="adminsetups"/>');` but no actin call...Please help me again.

Comment: OK, try it another way, it should look like this! check out the update. This should work, i checked it by myself

Comment: Now my action is calling and everything is working fine. One additional doubt. I want to pass a parameter "id" to my actin class through this action.-> ` $("#targetDivToRefresh").load('your-struts2-action');` How can i do this?

Comment: @Jaiwo99 tried to pass id to my action like this ->`$("#myAdvanceDivBoxx").load('<s:url action='testing'><s:param name="id" value="'event.originalEvent.id'"/></s:url>');`  But nothing is happening. Please check this and suggest me a answer.

Comment: @AshutoshSingh Check out update again, i really should let you think about it by yourself

Comment: @Jaiwo99 Executed Succussfully.  Thankyou very much. _I tried but my mind is little dull. I am working hard to make my mind sharper_ Thanks again